# Model passed to view + accessible to end user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, viewmodel

Hi I am new to stack overflow.

I have started using asp.net mvc to develop a website.

I have a database that stores a lot of information, some of which I don't want to show the end user.

An example db table - Property.sql

```
Id, Address, Area, Price, Owner Phone no, Owner home address
```

I have created a view that is strongly typed to this db table (model) but the view only uses the 'Address', 'Area' and 'Price' field

This is a security question -

Can someone using fiddler or otherwise access the other fields passed to the view? Or, is the view generated first using the information that is required and then passed to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, views are rendered server-side *before* they are sent to the browser therefore it would be impossible for the client to see this information. However, it's not a great idea to leak domain models into your views, you should create view-specific models and pass those instead e.g.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And I would then use something like Automapper to map data between the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about exposing Model data to the view (client), use a View-Model specific to the page needs.

Yet, if you don't serialize your Model and only using it to fill some data in your View (on the server side) the extra data is not exposed to the client.